# make a auto adjustable QTextBrowser

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtextbrowser

hello i need make a auto adjustable QTextBrowser. 
It's means the height of the QBrowserText depend of the number of rows it contained, somebody can help me please ?

Comment: yes in fact it's real name it's QtextBrowser I made a mistake in writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this page: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/10240/
They used QDockWidget.
And here: http://www.mimec.org/node/383